# Why do I have to specify the index position using .map?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I get my array of objects from my mongoDB and it stores into notes using setNotes, but when I try to print the hooks array of notes, I have to specify the array index value in order to get the value otherwise it returns "undefined". I thought the "map" function does that for you, what is happening here?

Thank you.

```
function NoteDashboard(props) {
const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/list/").then((response) => {
      setNotes([response.data]);
    }, 1000);
  });
}, []);

notes.map((note, index) => console.log(note.title));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the square brackets, you are storing an array inside the main array.

```
setNotes([response.data]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was storing the array as another array so my notes was an array inside an array which was causing the problem. After combing the arrays the program worked as intended.